# Dynamically added checkbox inside jQuerymobile list view is not rendering properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

Dynamically added checkbox inside jQuerymobile list view is not rendering properly.

Find below the unorder list.  I have added a sample listitem in the HTML itself.

```
<ul data-role="listview" id="ul_address_list" >
  <li data-icon="false"><a href="#" class="add-container">
    <label class="add-container" data-corners="false">
      <input type="checkbox" value="true" />
      <label class="lbl_add-container">
        <h3>Header</h3>
        <p>Content</p>
      </label>
    </label>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Below is the output for the above code.  Which is rendering correct.

[image: The correct display]

Now I am trying to add the list item dynamically using append function using jQuery.

```
$.each(obj_address_list, function (ctr, obj) {
    $('#ul_address_list').append('<li data-icon="false">' +
        '<a href="#" class="add-container">' +
        '<label class="add-container" data-corners="false">' +
        '<input type="checkbox" value="true" />' +
        '<label class="lbl_add-container">' +
        '<h3>Header</h3>' +
        '<p>content</p></div>' +
        '</label>' +
        '</label>' +
        '</a>' +
        '</li>');
});
$('#ul_address_list').listview('refresh');
```

below is the output for the above code. Not displayed correctly.

[image: Not displayed correctly]

Why the listitem added dynamically is not rendering properly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add

```
$("[type=checkbox]").checkboxradio();
```

before

```
$('#ul_address_list').listview('refresh');
```

Or, call `.trigger("create");`

```
$('#ul_address_list').listview('refresh').trigger("create");
```

> **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/xqwqM/)**

Comment: both of your suggestions are working fine.  Thanks a lot.  I put the code like this `$("input[name=chk_address]").checkboxradio();` and this also works fine.

Answer (score 2):

You need to call the listview refresh inside your append function and add .trigger("create");.

```
$('#ul_address_list').append('<li data-icon="false">' +
  '<a href="#" class="add-container">' +
    '<label class="add-container" data-corners="false">' +
      '<input type="checkbox" value="true" />' +
      '<label class="lbl_add-container">' +
        '<h3>Header</h3>' +
        '<p>content</p></div>' +
      '</label>' +
    '</label>' +
  '</a>' +
'</li>').listview("refresh");
```

Check this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/eRsMV/5

Comment: If you see my example, it shows that adding the same thing you added in your answer, it's appending the new list element with the same css properties applied.

Comment: Simply that i forgot to add it on my answer. It's .trigger("create"); that was missing. http://jsfiddle.net/eRsMV/5/

Answer (score 0):

you have extra

```
});
```

just use

```
$('#ul_address_list').append('<li data-icon="false">' +
  '<a href="#" class="add-container">' +
    '<label class="add-container" data-corners="false">' +
      '<input type="checkbox" value="true" />' +
      '<label class="lbl_add-container">' +
        '<h3>Header</h3>' +
        '<p>content</p></div>' +
      '</label>' +
    '</label>' +
  '</a>' +
'</li>');

$('#ul_address_list').listview('refresh');
```

my advice is to use some editor like dreamweaver just to save your time.

http://jsfiddle.net/prollygeek/xqwqM/1/

Comment: @prollyGeed - Sorry that is a copy paste error.  I updated the question.

Comment: $('#ul_address_list').listview('refresh').trigger("create"); this is the correct answer , given by Omar

Comment: `obj_address_list` is a object list which will keep the for each loop to run for n times.  I haven't copied the entire code.  After adding `$("[type=checkbox]").checkboxradio();` it works fine.  Tks

Comment: ok and your code work properely by the way , check http://jsfiddle.net/prollygeek/xqwqM/1/  just as you said it needed to trigger checkbox once again.